# While loop not terminating with '\0'

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, character

This is a function to read character by character from a file and place then convert the string to a float but the while loop is not terminating when a '/0' is read.

GSF555 "Gas Filter - Ford Escort" 64.50 9 <-- this is what is read in but from " 64.50 "

PKL070 "Park Lens - Toyota Corolla" 36.50 8

The while loop goes past the '/0' and also reads " 9" and characters from the next line of data.

I  just have `printf` to see what was going wrong.

```
float getPrice(FILE * in){
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    char str[10];
    ch = fgetc(in);
    printf("INDEX + NUMBER = %d %c\n", i, ch);
    if(ch == '\0')
        ch = fgetc(in);
    str[i++] = ch;
    while(ch != '\0' && i < 10){
        str[i++] = ch;
        printf("Index I = %d\n", i);
        ch = fgetc(in);
        printf("3 %c\n",ch);
    }
    printf("STRING = %s\n", str);
    return atof(str);
}
```

Comment: `str` is not necessarily null character terminated before it is printed.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure from what I am seeing in your post where the \0 you are referring to is, but I can see a couple of problems.

First, fgetc returns an integer, not a character.  This can be important for testing for the end-of-file, since the EOF is an integer with value -1, not a character which typically takes values of 0-255.  You can change the declaration of ch to be an int, not a char.  (Don't worry, this will not affect the print of ch with %c.)

Also, if you are trying to detect the end-of-line by testing with \0, it may not work.  The end-of-line is the newline, \n.  Depending on the underlying operating system, this may be take two characters, not one.  You should be able to compare ch if declared as an int to the newline character, but it may not work if you keep ch as a char, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not reading till the end-of-line as i stated above it will start at " 6" and is suppose to end with "0" giving you "6.50" at the end of the function.

Comment: @hinkatana '0' and '\0' are not at all the same thing.

Comment: I think intead of ch != '0' you could use isdigit(ch) in the while condition.  That will stop the loop when the space is read.  You will need to add #include <ctype.h> at the top of the program.

Answer (score 1):

> the while loop is not terminating when a '/0' is read.

There's no such thing as '/0' (barring multibyte characters, for the pedants), and '\0' is a NUL whereas '0' is the zero digit. So replace those '\0' in your program with '0'. Although looking for '0' is odd; it's much more common to look for a delimiter, such as whitespace (or any other non-digit) that comes after the number.

Comment: Firstly i cannot guarantee the price for an item would be ending with a '0' suppose it had '999.99' so why would i terminate with a '0' I want the number.

Comment: @hinkatana You **wrote** 'is suppose to end with "0"', so I took you to mean that you wanted to look for a '0'; *as I wrote in my answer*, that's an odd thing to do. I have no idea why you're looking for a '\0', as there isn't one in the input, after the number or anywhere else. *As I wrote in my answer*, you ought to be looking for the whitespace that follows the number.